# Как память из флешки переместить на диск?

Tags: память, диск, пк

Разделил флешку на 2 части - и теперь хочу вторую часть переместить на диск 0 (там Диск C и Диск D).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это невозможно.... память разделяется только внутри элемента. На изображении даже видно как область диска 0 отделена от области диска 1

Comment: Это равносильно тому, что иметь две корзинки и свободное место второй корзины переместить в первую.....

Comment: Пилой, наверное)) Отпилите часть флешки и приварите к диску (шутка)

Comment: @AvidCoder но ведь тогда будет сложно вернуть место обратно на флешку, когда понадобится. Думаю лучше скотч или изолента

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто пилить надо ровно - и тогда можно будет моментом приклеить.

Comment: Кто мне на ответы минусы ставит? Нормальный ответ.

Comment: Странно делить крохотную флешку... Но если приспичило, то просто примонтируйте этот кусок как папку на основном диске.

Comment: @AvidCoder Ответ бестолковый, логическое объединение разных физических носителей, и даже носителей на разных машинах - обычная практика.

Comment: @user7860670 вопрос звучит: "Как память из флешки переместить память на д дискразделил". Я поменял его на "Как память из флешки переместить на диск?". Переместить нельзя. Логическое объединение - это другая тема. Здесь явно не об этом речь.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, для этого есть отдельная программа, правда там куча нюансов. То есть физически всё хранится на флешке, но отображается таким образом, будто это записано на диск. Название к сожалению забыл, если сейчас найду, то скину.

Comment: В виндовс есть такая штука как "динамические диски" можно сделать через это, но не уверен что можно это провернуть с системным диском

Comment: Присоединяйте флешку как папку к диску, в программе работы с дисками есть такое.